# Cloud Object Storage buckets (what meaning / usage for) IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

Simple question

What is Cloud Object Storage buckets exactly ?

I use IBM Assistant with node.js (just with apikey, url and wordkspace_id) but I never use this Cloud Object Storage buckets and CRN. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the IBM Watson Assistant service on IBM Cloud? What is the context for your question? Look at the "Object Storage" service for the full docs on storage buckets

Comment: Yes I use IBM Watson Assistant with my own node.js application. And now, just reviewing potencial actions needed (to keep my app running), I saw this "iam_serviceid_crn" (I've never used this) and looking for it (CRN), I discovered this "Cloud Object Storage bucket" that I never used also.

But, so... I just reviewing potential actions that I need to take to keep all my app running. Maybe not necessary, I don't use IBM cloud storage. But I'm curious about that, whats is it, and why to use with Watson Assistant. or possible use with node.js ? I don't know.